# Reload form to anchor after submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a big form in PHP with several tables, each of one calculates a sum (of price and quantity) and then there's one at the end that calculates the total.
The structure is, more or less, this:

```
<form action="" id="purchase_form">
    <div id="purchase_1">
        <table>
            <input id="price_1">
            <input id="quantity_1">

            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Click here to calculate the partial">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="purchase_2">
        <table>
            <input id="price_2">
            <input id="quantity_2">

            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Click here to calculate the partial">
        </table>
    </div>

    <tr>
        <td id="price_sum"><?php *script* ?></td>
        <td id="quantity_sum"><?php *script* ?></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Now, when I click on submit to calculate the "partial", it gives me the total, at the same time. I know it's not a *state-of-the-art* form, but anyway, just try to turn a blind eye on that.

What I want is, when I click on submit button, to have the page reloaded showing the form I have clicked on. Like, if I click on submit of the #purchase_1 table, I want the page to reload on #purchase_1 table, and so on.

Is it possible to do that with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, it's not possible. You could make the calculations on the client side, provided that they aren't complex. If you perform some magic stuff on the backend stuff and you can't count the price on the client side, you could make a xhr request on the form submit (NOTE: the form won't be submitted as usually, so the page won't be reloaded).

If you chose the second option, the perfection solution would be to retrieve only the needed piece of html. It's not compulsory, though. You may use the following code in both cases:

```
var form = document.getElementById("purchase_form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // we prevent the default action, which is a submit for the form element

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // create a new XHR object.
  xhr.open("GET", form.action, true); // open the async connection
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""); // you could use DOMParser aswell, but parsing html via DOMParser is not supported in in Safari < 7.1 and IE < 10.
    doc.documentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", xhr.response);

    // now you would have to retrieve the element where the partial price is displayed and insert that value to desired element.
    // you can do it like document.querySelector(desiredElement).textContent = doc.querySelector(selectorToElementToGetValueFrom).textContent 

  });
  xhr.addEventListener("error", function() {
    // error happened... you can handle the action for exception here
  });
  xhr.send(new FormData(form));
});
```

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask me.